# Add programmatically constraint to text view

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have construction like follow:

[image]

You can see that i add fixed height constraint for text view. However, its wrong, because i cant know text view height before app launch. I will load data and sometime height might be 100, and next time it will be 1000, depending on content.

What i want is, calculate expected text view height and add fixed height constraint programmatically, before view load.

Comment: Apply constraint programmatically (via IBOUTLET) and provide the value on runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is, to create IBOutlet of your constraint. IBOutlet for constraint is created in same way as you create Outlet for view elements. Once you create outlet you'll have

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintName;
```

added in your code. All you have to do next is set the text for your text view and change the constraint.

```
constraintName.constant = 50 //assuming 50 is height of your text view.
```

Once you update constraint call

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

`layoutIfNeeded` forces the receiver to layout its subviews immediately if required.

Answer (score 1):

add reference outlet for the height constraint.
change constraint outlet value constant based on the content value height.

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintTextviewHeight;

change value by programatically as follows
constraintTextviewHeight.constant=100 or 200 or any required height

Comment: provide me example code snippet? I have neved make outlet refference for constraints. In which method should i change it value, before view load?

Comment: click on constraint you can get outlet connection option will be there.add outlet.Then change value in viewdidload

Comment: in which method should i do that before view is loaded?

Comment: Update the value of constraint after your have set the text in your textview.

Answer (score 0):

You can also update and access any constraints without `IBOutlet` reference of your constraint. Try [KVConstraintExtensionsMaster](https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster) library.

```
/** applyHeightConstraint method will add a new height constraint on yourView 
  * If yourView already have height constraint, It will update the constraint constant too. 
  */
  [yourView applyHeightConstraint:80]; // this will add height constraint
  [yourView applyHeightConstraint:100]; // this will updates height constraint

// To access height constraint 
  [yourView accessAppliedConstraintByAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight completion:^(NSLayoutConstraint *expectedConstraint){
    if (expectedConstraint) {
        // do here additional stuff 
        expectedConstraint.constant = 150;
        // To update constant with nice animation
        [yourView updateModifyConstraintsWithAnimation:NULL];
    }
}];
```